File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation. Debugging click error
My code working in the desktop browser(chrome) but gives the error I mentioned in the Android webview(chrome). (File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation. Debugging click error)
It was working in Angular version 14, but this problem occurred after upgrading to 15. Current material version "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
<input
    id="hiddenInputAcquire"
    class="hidden-input-acquire"
    hidden
    type="file"
    accept="image/*"
    capture="environment"
    onclick="this.value = null"
    (change)="onUploadPicture($event)" />

<button
        mat-icon-button
        color="accent"
        matTooltip="{{ 'COMMON.PICTURE_TOOLTIP_ACQUIRE' | translate }}"
        (click)="acquireImage()">
        <mat-icon>photo_camera</mat-icon>
      </button>

acquireImage() {
    if (this.isCaptureSupported()) {
      const inputAcquire = document.getElementById('hiddenInputAcquire') as HTMLInputElement;
      if (inputAcquire) {
        //error appears here
        inputAcquire.click();
      }
      return;
    }

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AcquireImageDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.useToCropExistingImage = undefined;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.interactiveCropping = this.useCropper;
    this.acquireDialogSub?.unsubscribe();
    this.acquireDialogSub = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res: AcquireImageDialogResult) => {
      if (res.isImageProvided) {
        this.assignPicture(res.fileId);
      }
    });
  }

private isCaptureSupported() {
    const ele = document.createElement('input');

    return 'capture' in ele;
  }

async onUploadPicture(event: Event) {
    const pictureFiles = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

    if (pictureFiles) {
      const filesData = Array.from(pictureFiles);
      if (filesData.length === 1) {
        if (this.useCropper) {
          const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AcquireImageDialogComponent);
          dialogRef.componentInstance.useToCropExistingImage = filesData[0];
          dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res: AcquireImageDialogResult) => {
            if (res.isImageProvided) {
              this.assignPicture(res.fileId);
            }
          });
        } else {
          await this.fileUploadService.upload(filesData, ObjectVisibility.OV_DEFAULT).then((result) => {
            if (result.length === 1) {
              this.assignPicture(result[0]);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }


I tried this.hiddenInputAcquire.nativeElement.click();



gives the error I mentioned:
please include a copy-paste of that error message in the question


Why do you want to simulate a click on the hiddenInputAcquire button instead of simply calling the hiddenInputAcquire action?

Because only HTMLInputElements have the files property, I cannot do this with a button, and I cannot give the button an input type property. I updated the code line, you can check it from there.

You could style your input to look like a button for a user to interact with it directly

Just created a fresh stackblitz - works in desktop Safari and Chrome. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zhxjif?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=package.json,src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter

sounds like it's checking if the event isTrusted.  (it won't be if it's generated via JS)

@Sergey Thank you for answer. I did the same solution. Its working on desktop but on Android webview showing a user activation error.

The easiest thing to do here is to use the native input to receive the click. Either by styling it as a button. Or, you could make it transparent, position specifically over the button so it would receive user click events (however, it wouldn't work if user decides to use keyboard to navigate to the element).

@Sergey it would work just fine if you gave visible button `tabindex="-1", so the 'visible' button can't receive focus, and instead the real  would.

@CeeMcSharpface 1. What version of chrome did it used to work in? 2. Does it work in Firefox? 3. Have you tried debugging the android device in-progress using Remote Debugging to check what errors you get in the console? 4. Even if you get no errors, add in a console.log and verify the button is actually receiving a click.

EliezerBerlin same chrome version, we just updated angular from 14 to 15. It was working fine on 14, but when I debug on 15, I get this error "File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation". I will try to test it with the code shared by @SELA below. If it does not work, I will design the entry as you said and let you know.


@Sergey Thank you for your answer. I did the same solution. It's working on
desktop but on Android webview showing a user activation error.

Since the @Sergey approach is kind of a hacky way of achieving it and ends up in an error. You can try something like below:
Use angular template reference to your benefit(@ViewChild). Your template should look like below:
HTML:
<input
  #hiddenInputAcquire
  id="hiddenInputAcquire"
  class="hidden-input-acquire"
  hidden
  type="file"
  accept="image/*"
  capture="environment"
  (click)="resetInputValue($event)"
  (change)="onUploadPicture($event)" />

<button
  mat-icon-button
  color="accent"
  matTooltip="{{ 'COMMON.PICTURE_TOOLTIP_ACQUIRE' | translate }}"
  (click)="acquireImage()">
  <mat-icon>photo_camera</mat-icon>
</button>

Your component.ts should look alike something below:
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('hiddenInputAcquire') hiddenInputAcquire!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  acquireImage() {
    if (this.isCaptureSupported()) {
      const inputAcquire = this.hiddenInputAcquire.nativeElement;
      if (inputAcquire) {
        inputAcquire.click();
      }
      return;
    }

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AcquireImageDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.useToCropExistingImage = undefined;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.interactiveCropping = this.useCropper;
    this.acquireDialogSub?.unsubscribe();
    this.acquireDialogSub = dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res: AcquireImageDialogResult) => {
      if (res.isImageProvided) {
        this.assignPicture(res.fileId);
      }
    });
  }

  isCaptureSupported() {
    const ele = document.createElement('input');
    return 'capture' in ele;
  }

  async onUploadPicture(event: Event) {
    const pictureFiles = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
    if (pictureFiles) {
      const filesData = Array.from(pictureFiles);
      if (filesData.length === 1) {
        if (this.useCropper) {
          const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AcquireImageDialogComponent);
          dialogRef.componentInstance.useToCropExistingImage = filesData[0];
          dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res: AcquireImageDialogResult) => {
            if (res.isImageProvided) {
              this.assignPicture(res.fileId);
            }
          });
        } else {
          await this.fileUploadService.upload(filesData, ObjectVisibility.OV_DEFAULT).then((result) => {
            if (result.length === 1) {
              this.assignPicture(result[0]);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  resetInputValue(event: Event) {
    (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value = '';
  }
}

By doing the above you are having #hiddenInputAcquire template variable.
ViewChild: @ViewChild('hiddenInputAcquire') will have hold of it in the component. Once the input HTML element is clicked event is triggered within the same call stack as the button's click event handler programmatically.

As @Sergey said, simply position the file upload  on top of your button using
input[type="file"]{
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

or something.
That way, when users click on your button, they're genuinely clicking on the <input type="file">, so it'll open as expected. (And of course, you can control whether it activates using using *ngIf or [hidden] or something as needed, if necessary.)
